# Python Flask not displaying contents with render_template()

Tags: python, html, flask

When I try running my Flask program, all I see is the background color. No content from the HTML is displayed when I enter `localhost:5000/index` on browser.

My folder structure is like this:

Flask

---Test.py

---static

------styles

---------main.css

---templates

------base.html

------home.html

---**pycache**

Codes given below:

Test.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home/")
def home(name):
    return render_template("home.html", name=name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{{ name }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/main.css') }}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <!-- Jinja directives: page contents will go between them -->
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}

<h1>{{ name }}</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

main.css

```
body {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #000;
    background: #407189;
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    margin: 2em auto;
    width: 740px;
    padding: 2em 4em;
    background: #f1f7dc;
}

h1, h2 {
    font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 0;
                padding-bottom: 1em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

p {
    font-size: 1.4em;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    body {
        background: #f1f7dc;
    }
    #container {
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 2em;
    }
}
```

Comment: You just have to say `http://localhost:5000/index/` and not `http://localhost:5000/index` because that is a route which is not implemented. Alternatively you can call `http://localhost:5000/`

Comment: @Shiv using just `localhost:5000` doesn't display anything either

Comment: You have two routes defined one of them is '/' thus `http://localhost:5000/` or `http://localhost:5000/index/` will work. I see no way why it won't work.

Comment: I have tried using both as well as `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`. It is simply a blank screen that I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **base.html** change `{% block content %}` to `{% block body %}`

```
    <div id="container">
      <!-- Jinja directives: page contents will go between them -->
      {% block body %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
```

Comment: I just tried making that change. I pressed CTRL+C in Terminal, and then ran the commands `set FLASK_APP=Test.py` and then `flask run`. Are these the incorrect ways to do this? Because I still just see a blank screen when reloading the page

Comment: You just have to do `python Test.py` in the terminal to get it running. This works for me.

Comment: Just tried doing `python Test.py` and then loading `localhost:5000` from Firefox and Chrome. Both still blank. I added my main.css file to the code. Is there any issue with that?

Comment: Since you are using the template folder, could you modify this - `app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates", static_folder='static')` I'm not sure why you are facing the issue as I'm able to view the page.

Comment: @AnsarAl Can you make a small git repo with requirements file and I will test it myself.

Comment: @Shiv by requirements file, you mean the requirements of my assignment??

Comment: @AnsarAl no the requriements.txt to create the environment. Do not worry about it. Just put all your code in a public git repo and I can try running it.

Comment: @AnsarAl What vnk has suggested works and I tested your code. It is working. You are doing something else wrong. Can you make a video of your environment and show what you are doing?

Comment: Do you have Discord that I can contact you on to show you how I am trying to run it?

Comment: @AnsarAl Do you use the same folder structure as git repository?

Comment: No I was not able to upload folders to the github, so i just added each file. The files are in the structure I showed. I can show you a video too on discord

Comment: Give me 10 min and I will help you over discord. I am in between some stuff.

Comment: I have sent friend request with Anonymōus#0884 but I cannot speak English well, we will have to type.

Comment: Changing to `blocks body` did the trick